# Проверка json перед Unmarshal

Tags: golang

Например я получаю две даты в json:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(request.Body, 1048576))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := request.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var dateInterval DateInterval

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &dateInterval); err != nil {
        if err := json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(err); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(dateInterval)
```

Но если какоето из полей пустое то ставится стандартная дата:

`{0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}`

Как мне проверить пустые поля приходят или нет?

Comment: Как вариант - из json сначала в string, если не пустая строка, то string -> дата

Comment: А какое значение должно быть в структуре, если значение в json отсутствует?

Comment: Какое значение? Это тоже вопрос.

Comment: Можно как вариант в структуре сделать ссылку, а не статическое значение. Тогда у вас должен получится nil после парсинга json-а

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать интерфейс `json.Unmarshaler` своего типа `time`, Примерно как-то так:

```
const timeLayout = time.RFC3339

type MyTime struct {
   time.Time
}

type MyStructure struct {
    Time1 *MyTime `json:"time1"`
    Time2 *MyTime `json:"time2,string,omitempty"`
}

func (t *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {
    timeStr := strings.Trim(string(data), `""`)
    t.Time, err = time.Parse(timeLayout, timeStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("json: con not conver %+v to time", timeStr)
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    str := []byte(`{"time1":"2018-02-08T10:41:01+05:00"}`)
    my := MyStructure{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(str, &my)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(my)
}
```

Рабочий пример: https://play.golang.org/p/S5eeAScnRPd